# Build Vim with lua on Linux Mint

Tags: vim, build, lua, linux-mint

This is what I did:

```
# Install lua
curl -R -O http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.2.2.tar.gz
tar zxf lua-5.2.2.tar.gz
cd lua-5.2.2
sudo make linux install

# build vim
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libgnome2-dev libgnomeui-dev \
libgtk2.0-dev libatk1.0-dev libbonoboui2-dev \
libcairo2-dev libx11-dev libxpm-dev libxt-dev python-dev ruby-dev mercurial
sudo apt-get remove vim vim-runtime gvim
sudo apt-get remove vim-tiny vim-common vim-gui-common
cd ~
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/vim/
cd vim
./configure --with-features=huge \
            --enable-rubyinterp \
            --enable-pythoninterp \
            --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7-config \
            --enable-perlinterp \
            --enable-gui=gtk2 --enable-cscope --prefix=/usr \
            --enable-luainterp \
            --with-lua-prefix=/usr/local/bin/lua
make VIMRUNTIMEDIR=/usr/share/vim/vim74
sudo make install
```

But the `./configure` step returns:

```
checking --enable-luainterp argument... yes
checking --with-lua-prefix argument... /usr/local/bin/lua
checking --with-luajit... no
checking for lua... (cached) /usr/local/bin/lua
checking Lua version... (cached) 5.2
checking if lua.h can be found in /usr/local/bin/lua/include... no
checking if lua.h can be found in /usr/local/bin/lua/include/lua5.2... no
```

I can verify that lua.h can't be found in those locations, but I don't know where it can be found.

Comment: You need the header files indeed, presumably in a package called something like `lua-dev` (under Ubuntu, I assume it's `libtolua-dev`, I'm not sure what it would be in Mint).

Comment: I've tried `sudo apt-get install lua50 liblua50-dev liblualib50-dev` but then the ./configure step errored out.  This makes me reluctant to follow any more incomplete suggestions.

Comment: It’s strange that `configure` is looking in `/usr/local/bin/lua/include/` instead of `/usr/local/include/`.

Comment: @lhf, that would be because of `--with-lua-prefix=/usr/local/bin/lua`, I think.

Comment: By default it looks in /usr/local/bin/include.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit**

I tried this again, ran into problems, and discovered a package `vim-nox` that already has vim support.

**Original answer**

I'm not entirely sure how I did this in the end, but thanks to @wrikken for the tip about headers.

```
# Install lua from binaries (these are out-of-date but at least they worked).
sudo apt-get install lua50 liblua50-dev liblualib50-dev

# Remove old vims
sudo apt-get remove vim vim-runtime gvim
sudo apt-get remove vim-tiny vim-common vim-gui-common

# Download and build a new vim
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libgnome2-dev libgnomeui-dev \
libgtk2.0-dev libatk1.0-dev libbonoboui2-dev \
libcairo2-dev libx11-dev libxpm-dev libxt-dev python-dev ruby-dev mercurial
cd ~
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/vim/
cd vim
cd ~/vim
./configure --with-features=huge \                                            
            --enable-rubyinterp \
            --enable-pythoninterp \
            --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7-config \
            --enable-perlinterp \
            --enable-gui=gtk2 --enable-cscope --prefix=/usr \
            --enable-luainterp \
            --with-lua-prefix=/usr/local
```

At this point, check the output of ./configure to see that it found lua.h.  If not, find out where it is (I'm afraid I can't remember where it was).  Symlink to it in /usr/local with e.g. `sudo ln -s ../lua.h` and rerun ./configure.

Finally:

```
sudo make VIMRUNTIMEDIR=/usr/share/vim/vim74       
sudo make install
```

If it still won't work, post on a forum somewhere and go for a walk in the outdoors.  You'll find it suddenly starts to behave.

Comment: On my debian wheezy install this file is in `/usr/include/lua50/lua.h`. You can find it using `find /usr -name lua.h`.

Comment: Perhaps you could compile vim on a machine where you have admin rights, for the machine where you don't have rights.

Comment: @Werner you can install anywhere (including your own home) using `--prefix`. For example: `./configure [other options] --prefix=/home/werner/bin/vim`

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install liblua5.1-dev
```

copy all files from `/usr/include/lua5.1/` to `/usr/include/lua5.1/include/`

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblua5.1.so /usr/local/lib/liblua.so
```

Go to the vim source folder

```
 cd src
 make distclean
 clear
 ./configure --with-features=huge --enable-cscope --enable-pythoninterp=yes --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-multibyte --enable-fontset --enable-gui=gnome2 --disable-netbeans --enable-luainterp=yes --with-lua-prefix=/usr/include/lua5.1 --enable-largefile --enable-rubyinterp
 sudo make
 sudo make install
```

This will also install the GUI version, remove the `--enable-gui=gnome2` if you will only use it in the command line.

Most of these I found it in [here](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim/issues/31)